# подскажите пожалуйста, как реализовать динамический блок на kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

нужно сделать чтоб потянул за иконку - раскрывается блок - потянул вверх - закрывается. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Вопрос не совсем понятен, но я так понимаю вам нужен MotionLayout https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/motionlayout/examples